# How do I curve text but keep orientation of letters?

Tags: inkscape, text-on-path

I'm trying to wrap text around a circle in Inkscape, without disturbing the vertical orientation of the letters. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for Inkscape 1.3

Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy automatic way to do this using the text on a path functionality. This is a slightly different method from the other answer, but still entirely manual. I think it's sufficiently different to warrant another answer.

Type all the text you need and do *Path > Object to Path*, then *Path > Split Path*, to separate all the letters.

The placement of the centre letters and numbers can be snapped to the intersection of the guide circles and radial spoke guides, but the others can be eye-balled either side of them while still snapping the object centres to the circle path. This will allow for the adjustment of the letter spacing visually for balance.

Here are the guides, circle placements and snapping options I would suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Place them manually one by one. It's easy if there's not too many letters. Have each letter as separate object. They snap easily if you have the snapping ON.

In the next example letters A,B and C are converted to paths (Path -> Object to Path) to make possible they snap at every node. Letters X,Y and Z are text objects. They snap well only at their centers.

[image]

You can make the path invisible in the objects panel when you are ready. Do not delete it if there's no special reason to do it.

If it happens that you want to make a copy of the face of the old phone draw at first a polygon or a star as your angle marker and a few circles as your paths.

Instead of the star or polygon you can also use rotated copies of a straight line. It's tried in the next image:

[image]